# Unexpected String Results

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to check values entered into two input boxes, if both values are zero then the `MsgBox` should display "Stop!" (I will change this later to exiting the sub but I am using a MsgBox for testing)

From testing I've seen these results:

- A zero in both strings produces the expected message box.
- A non zero in the first string followed by any non zero value in the second string does nothing (as expected).
- A zero in the first string followed by a second string value equal to or greater than 10 produces the message box (unexpected).

I've also noticed that if the second string is 6-9 it is displayed as `x.00000000000001%`. I think this is a floating point issue and could be related? This behaviour occurs without the `IF... InStr` function too.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Models()
    Dim MinPer As String, MaxPer As String, Frmula As String
    Dim Data As Worksheet, Results As Worksheet
    Set Data = Sheets("Data")
    Set Results = Sheets("Results")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MinPer = 1 - InputBox("Enter Minimum Threshold Percentage, do not include the % symbol", _
    "Minimum?") / 100
    MaxPer = 1 + InputBox("Enter Maximum Threshold Percentage, do not include the % symbol", _
    "Maximum?") / 100


    If (InStr(MinPer, "0") = 0) And (InStr(MaxPer, "0") = 0) Then
    MsgBox "STOP!"
    End If

    ' Remainder of code...
```

This is the most interesting problem I've come across so far in VBA and welcome any discussion about it.

**Edit:** I use this code to display on screen the paramaters for the end-user to see. Hence how I noticed the .00000000001% issue:

```
    .Range("D2").Value = "Min is " & 100 - MinPer * 100 & "%"
    .Range("D3").Value = "Max is " & MaxPer * 100 - 100 & "%"
```

Comment: what are you trying to test for? also, converting a calculation to a string is going to produce some interesting results too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things

**1)** Declare `MinPer`, `MaxPer` as `Long` or a `Double` and not a `String` as you are storing outputs from a calculation

**2)** Don't directly use the `InputBox` in the calculations. Store them in a variable and then if the input is valid then use them in the calculation

```
Dim MinPer As Double, MaxPer As Double, Frmula As String
Dim Data As Worksheet, Results As Worksheet
Dim n1 As Long, n2 As Long

Set Data = Sheets("Data")
Set Results = Sheets("Results")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
n1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Minimum Threshold Percentage, do not include the % symbol", _
Title:="Minimum?", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

If n1 = False Then
    MsgBox "User cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
n2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Maximum Threshold Percentage, do not include the % symbol", _
Title:="Maximum?", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

If n2 = False Then
    MsgBox "User cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End If

If n1 = 0 And n2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox "STOP!"
End If

MinPer = 1 - (Val(n1) / 100)
MaxPer = 1 + (Val(n2) / 100)
```

Comment: Entering non numeric values is producing type mismatch errors instead of the `not a valid input` msgbox. The value of MinPer and MaxPer are not as expected, I'm sure the arithmatic is right but not getting the correct values.. e.g  N1 = 5 and N2 = 6 should produce MinPer = 0.95 and MaxPer = 1.06 but both equal 1.

Comment: Just leaving office, will come back to this when home.

Comment: Updated the post. Please test it now.

Comment: Still producing MinPer and MaxPer = 1. Getting correct msgbox error now for non numeric inputs but no stop msgbox for 0 inputs.

Comment: Input Box for Min = 5, Input Box for Max = 6 produces 1. Just tried inputmin=50, inputmax=60 got Minper = 0 Maxper = 2

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Trap if user enters 0 in inputboxes?

Comment: Do we need additional parenthesis for Min/Maxper?

Comment: Yes if double zero entered then Ill display a msgbox and exit sub

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13686/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-alistair-weir)

Comment: Use `Application.InputBox`, it has a `Type` parameter that lets you limit the input to numbers. You can skip the `IsNumeric` check, however you would need to check if the return value is `False` (user cancels InputBox)

Comment: @JimmyPena: + 1 nice Suggestion. Incorporated in the code. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout My bad, the return value is actually zero, help docs say it returns `False` but testing shows otherwise.

Comment: @JimmyPena: It returns false when user presses cancel. I just tested it. Which is same as 0 :) So both will work.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Silly me, I just realized I was using a Long variable to test it. `CLng(False) = 0`!

Comment: Yes it returns false when user presses cancel but also returns false when user enters zero. The user should be able to enter zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the number "10" has a "0" in the string (second character) so both evaluate to true.

Try this instead:

```
If (MinPer = "0") And (MaxPer = "0") Then
    MsgBox "STOP!"
End If
```

For additional control save the user input (MinPer , MaxPer) and THEN text them for validity before performing nay mathematical operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

InStr(MinPer, "0") is just checking to see whether the string contains a zero
character.

You need to convert the string value to an integer.  Use the IsNumeric and CInt functions
to do that.  See this URL:

[vba convert string to int if string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202074/vba-convert-string-to-int-if-string-is-a-number)

```
Dim minPerINT as Integer
Dim maxPerINT as Integer

If IsNumeric(minPer) Then
    minPerINT = CInt(minPer)
Else
    minPerINT = 0
End If
If IsNumeric(maxPer) Then
    maxPerINT = CInt(maxPer)
Else
    maxPerINT = 0
End If

If minPerINT = 0 and maxPerINT=0 Then
    MsgBox "STOP!"
End If
```

Depending on what data can be entered It may also be a good idea to check if the length
of the data is zero using the len() function.