# How to calculate with sheet names as integers?

Tags: vba, excel

I have many sheets(about 1000) with names as integer number like: 1 2 3 5 7 10 etc. They are ascending but not consistent, like I wrote.
I have vba code that create new sheet with numbername from inputbox, after the activesheet(I activate sheet 3, run the code, enter 4 in inputbox and it creates sheet 4 after 3). What I need is solution how to (example): create a new sheet with name 4 after the sheetnumber 3, without haveing to be on sheet 3.

Comment: How to calculate with sheet names as integers? -> Use CInt() |
Is this somewaht similar to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202074/vba-convert-string-to-int-if-string-is-a-number  ?

Comment: No, that would be for cell content. I can't come up with mathematical solution. I might be able to code it, but I don't understand the logic.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate or ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate to switch in your code to the right sheet, make a new one and avtivate the sheet u where in before. I don't get how you actual question is the same as your headline. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well what you have just suggested is what I actually do. Problem is I have over 1000 sheets and it is not practical to search for next sheet lower than you need, to open needed sheet after it. I wan't vba to do that to preserve my working time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code with go through all the sheets. When it reaches one with a larger number it will insert the new sheet before it.

```
Public Sub Test()
    AddSheetWithNumber shNum:=4
End Sub

Public Sub AddSheetWithNumber(shNum As Long)

    With ThisWorkbook

        Dim sh As Worksheet
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            ' Find first sheet with number greater than new sheet number
            If CLng(sh.Name) > shNum Then
                ' Add worksheet before sheet with larger number
                .Worksheets.Add before:=sh
                ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(shNum)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I ment and want. Can you just subscribe what are CLng and CStr. ? TY

Comment: CLng converts a string to an integer -the sheet name is a string so you need to convert it to a number to compare. CStr converts a number to a string - you need to convert the new sheet number to a string so you can assign it as the sheet name.

Comment: @Jelovac That this was the correct answer wasn't clear to me from your question, it might be worth editing your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with similar solution before I saw your example Paul. It might be usefull as well:

```
Sub New_Sheet()

Dim ExistingSheet As Integer
Dim NewSheet As Integer
On Error GoTo 30
NewSheet = InputBox("Enter new sheet:", "NEW SHEET")


For i = 3 To Sheets.Count - 3 'this is my work range
ExistingSheet = Sheets(i).Name
If ExistingSheet = NewSheet Then
 MsgBox ("That sheet already exist!")
 Sheets(i).Activate
 GoTo 30
Else
    On Error GoTo 10     'last 4 sheets have textual name like (subtotal, partners, etc) so error came up if I want to add sheet with bigest number(because it's comparing a textual name)
    If NewSheet > ExistingSheet Then   'error came up only in that case for now, so I make it place biggest sheet before textual one.
     GoTo 20
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Empty Card").Copy _
        after:=Sheets(i - 1)                        'Sheet with formulas and tables prepared for work
        ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheet
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13) = ActiveSheet.Name
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If
20 Next i
10      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Empty card").Copy _
        after:=Sheets(i - 1)      'didn't know of "befor" command
        ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheet
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13) = ActiveSheet.Name
30 Exit Sub

End Sub
```