# How do I remove the leading 0's from a number?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove all the leading 0's from the numbers in this column, without affecting the rows that start with a letter.

[image]

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to include in your question what you have tried and what aspect of it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a non-VBA solution, you can highlight the entire row and go to Data>Text-To-Columns and then hit "Finish". Numbers will be converted to numeric format and strings will remain untouched.

For a VBA solution, you could iterate through the cells:

```
 For each rngCell in Sheet1.Columns("A").Cells

 Next rngCell
```

And within that iteration, use `isnumeric()` to test before replacing

```
 If isnumeric(rngCell.value) Then rngCell.value = rngCell.value + 0
```

Or something along those lines. You could also record that text-to-columns bit and just sub out your column's range in the VBA. Depending on how much control you need over your data transformation.

Comment: ... and of course the number format shouldn't be something like this: `rngCell.NumberFormat = "0000000000"` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another Non VBA Solution... (**Simplest of all**)

1. Highlight the data
2. You will see an Exclamation Mark next to your data as shown in screenshot. Click on it
3. Click on `Convert To number` and you are done :)

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use this formula. my formula source data starts from B3.

```
=REPLACE(B3,1,FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B3,0,"")),B3)-1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: i forgot to check OP tag.. wasted my time

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the cell to a number and then back to string - if it fails it already was a string.
[vba convert string to int if string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202074/vba-convert-string-to-int-if-string-is-a-number)

**Edit:**

Try to solve it with an regex:

```
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "^0*"
End With

If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
    strInput = regEx.Replace(strInput, "")
End If
```

Source: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: This won't fulfill the requirement exactly. Some start with zeros but still have chars in them.

Comment: I just saw that. then your could use the regex `^0*` and replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a formula with or without VBA:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Value(A1)),Value(A1),A1)
```

Comment: Yes, of course i have tested it, works perfectly. Didn't it work for you?

Comment: I am working on Excel 2016. As per my understanding The ISNUMERIC function can only be used in VBA code in Microsoft Excel whereas you have mentioned that one can do it with a formula with or without VBA. Another Worksheetfunction ISNUMBER works fine for me in the formula.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thank you. I had to test it in an excel with an different language package. Lost in Translation.