# Format number to be able to search properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format some numbers where some have a leading zero so that I can then search them.

I am needing to format a set of numbers where all are 6 digits and some have a leading zero. I then have a separate code search those numbers for a specific one so the resulting format needs to be searchable. The first code below is the formatting I can't figure out and then the search code. If I simply do an "000000" for formatting I don't believe it works for my search anymore as those now become Special format. Help please?

```
Sub (First Code)

Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("O2:P" & lngLastRow).Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Dim SUPLCD As Range
Set SUPLCD = Range("Q2:Q")
With Selection
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.Value = Format(Selection, "000000")
End With

End Sub


Sub Worksheet()

 Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tempinterior")

    Dim wsTempinterior As Worksheet
    ' Note that .Add will activate the new sheet so we'll
    ' need to reactivate the worksheet that was previously active
    Set wsTempinterior = Worksheets.Add
    wsTempinterior.Name = "copy"

    ' Find the used range in columns A to K and copy over starting
    ' at cell A1 of wsGalreq
    Set rngData = Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Range("A:M"))

    ' Copy over the first row containing column headers
    j = 1
    rngData.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsTempinterior.Cells(j, 1)

    For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        ' Check cell of column 10 of row i and copy if matched
        If rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "026572" Or rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "435740" Or rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "622639" Then
            ' Copy over to wsDalreq from row j
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsTempinterior.Cells(j, 1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

With above code, the search doesn't pull the entries with those numbers I think because they are formatted as Special.

Comment: instead of `Selection.NumberFormat = "000000"` use `Selection.NumberFormat = "@"` and `Selection.value = format(selection,"000000")`

Comment: But you really should avoid using `Select`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: You will need to loop to do this.  BTW

Comment: @Scott Craner Does the above look right? (Can't figure out how to put the code in my comment)

    Dim SUPLCD As Range
    Set SUPLCD = Range("Q2:Q")
    With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Selection.Value = Format(Selection, "000000")
    End With

Comment: No, you are still using selection and you will need to loop.

Comment: Will go back to that other webpage you recommenced and try again.

Comment: While checking Excel values which might be integers, use the typecasting, explained in following URL: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202074/vba-convert-string-to-int-if-string-is-a-number/6202469".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to format `Col Q` to add a 0, you can accomplish your task with out formatting by using `Like` in your `If` statement. Because you are not clear about where the values are, you are formatting `Col Q` but searching `Col J`, I used `Col Q`.

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '("Tempinterior")

Dim rngData As Range
Set rngData = Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Range("A:M"))

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "copy"

    j = 1
    rngData.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("copy").Cells(j, 1) 'copy headers for rngData

    For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        If wsData.Cells(i, 17).Value Like "26572" Or Sheet1.Cells(i, 17).Value = "435740" Or _
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 17).Value = "622639" Then
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Copy").Cells(j, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First avoid `.Select` and you will need to loop the change:

```
Sub first()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet

        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("O2:P" & lngLastRow) 'specify the range which suits your purpose
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        Dim SUPLCD As Range
        Set SUPLCD = .Range("Q2:Q" & lngLastRow)

        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In SUPLCD
            rng.NumberFormat = "@"
            rng.Value = Format(rng.Value, "000000")
        Next rng

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a ton for typing this out for me. Ran into Run-Time error 424 around the "General". Do I need to do something else with that one also?